# Why am I able to send cross-domain ajax requests from the javascript console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How come when I go to almost any website, for example SO, if I open up the console, inject jQuery and send a cross-domain ajax request to a server I have running on my localhost, I don't get any errors as I would have expected? However, if I open up one of the webpages that I have written myself, and which is also running on my localhost (but on a different port from the one used by the server), if I try to send an ajax request from the console I get this message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:10000/. Request header field My-First-Header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

The ajax request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://localhost:10000',
    headers: {
        "My-First-Header":"first value",
        "My-Second-Header":"second value"
    }

})
```

To be clear, my question is not about how to fix this, but rather why I am even able to make cross-domain requests from most other websites (shouldn't they be not allowed?). Do these sites have some sort of mechanism set up that automatically bypasses the restrictions?

Request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:csrftoken=lxe5MaAlb9GC5lPGQpXtSj9HvCP0QhCz; PHPSESSID=uta0nlhlh8r1uimdklmt3v3ho1
Host:localhost:10000
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
Content-Length:3
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 16 May 2016 06:29:03 GMT
Server:TwistedWeb/16.0.0
```

Comment: Developer consoles are special; the browser understands that you're the source of the code, and since it's your own browser you should be able to do whatever you want.

Comment: _why I am even able to make cross-domain requests_....because that is what xhr does. The response is the final state of the request. i guess you misunderstood the request/respone.....!

Comment: @Pointy but why doesn't this work in my first example (when I send the request from my own webpage)?

Comment: @Jai but what about same-origin policy? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Can you post the response header that you can successfully get from your server (from an external page)? Use the network tab to see the request and response headers.

Comment: @slebetman updated, don't see any of the headers in the request which i would expect..

Comment: I just had a hunch that your local server was sending CORS headers. Looks like it doesn't so that saves me from posting a wrong answer :D

Comment: @slebetman Yeah, when I set CORS headers properly, it will allow the website that I am running on my own computer to send ajax requests to the server, but even without the headers it works properly for 'regular' websites

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious what's going on here: the browser simply handles code typed in the console differently than code run by the page itself.  It makes philosophical sense that it would work that way.  After all, the point of the Same-Origin Policy is to prevent XSS and CSRF attacks, and if a user opens up their console and sends cross-domain requests, they're just attacking themselves.

On the other hand, it *is* possible to trick users into performing XSS on themselves.  If you go to Facebook and open up the console, Facebook has code that logs a warning message telling ordinary users not to paste unknown code into the console because it could be malicious.  Apparently that's a problem they've seen.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I still don't understand why it wasn't working when I tried it with my own webpage that I am running on localhost? That is, if I try to send ajax from the console, I get the error message which you can see in the post

Answer (score 0):

This is called as CORS request.

By default all Cross Domain requests are blocked by most of the major browsers.
Most of the portals services that you are able to request cross domain does special settings in Response.  If you don't provide those settings at api level then your api will be blocked for cross domain requests.

These Response settings are as follows:
Response Header Need to have **access-control-allow-origin**  attribute.
access-control-allow-origin can specify * for every api service at global level.
access-control-allow-origin can specify specific method name for every api service separately..

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really answer my question. I know what a CORS request is, and I know about the response headers. However, my server clearly does not send those headers, and that's why I wish to know why it still works.